# Does the probability density evolve from nonuniform to uniform?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

I have been reading the book named Entropy, Order Parameters, and Complexity. And here is a question it ask

> Liouville’s theorem tells us that the total derivative of the probability density is zero; following
> the trajectory of a system, the local probability
> density never changes. The equilibrium states
> have probability densities that only depend on
> energy and number.  Something is wrong; if the
> probability density starts nonuniform, how can
> it become uniform?

The last sentence seems to imply that the probability density $\rho$ for points in phase space can evolve from a non-uniform distribution to an uniform distribution. I wonder why this is true.

In the book, below the referred paragraph, the book then shows that in an isolated system the entropy $S = \int k_B\rho\log\rho\ {\rm d}P{\rm d}Q$ is constant in time from a microscopic description that is from the perspective of points in momentum space P, and configuration space Q, thus entropy increases is an emergent property. I can understand what's going on here, but I don't know if such a fact is related to the last sentence of the referred paragraph.

Comment: Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/202522/how-is-liouvilles-theorem-compatible-with-the-second-law-of-thermodynamics